# How do I stop cout printing and wait for a response

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string INPUT;
    std::cout << "exp?:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "[1] r" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "[2] j" << std::endl;
   
    if (INPUT == "1") cout << "how your day[1]good[2] fnef" << std::endl;

    if (INPUT == "1") cout << "good" << std::endl;

    if (INPUT == "2") cout << "2" << std::endl; 
    
    return 0;
}
```

I want it to be able to take input so I can enter `1` and have it not output both `"exp [1]fjrnf [2] fnef"` and `"test1"`.

Comment: Don't learn from videos. [Get a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list?noredirect=1&lq=1).  And you're not reading any input; look up `std::cin`.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you are going to receive an input, put

```
std::cin >> INPUT;
```

All this does is take an input from the user and store it inside INPUT. You should probably put it after each time you want the user to select either good or 2.